# How to draw a traffic light sign?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm just going to admit that I'm useless at drawing images in LaTeX and revert to copy and paste and then adapting where possible. I had a look over at http://www.texample.net but couldn't find anything I could adapt. I want to create an image of a set of traffic lights with text to one side, like the image below. I want to use it as part of a score system where each colour means something. I probably looking for two items. The image below and then just the traffic lights where I could possibly put the score in the light it belongs.

[image]

PS: Sorry I have no MWE but don't know where to start with this. 
PPS: and sorry for putting up a help me draw this attached picture.

Comment: One possible starting point: `\begin{tikzpicture} \filldraw [fill=green,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm]; \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Why do you need it ? Maybe https://openclipart.org/search/?query=traffic+light could help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
    trafficlight/.style = {%
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        rounded corners,
        draw = blue!70,
        fill = blue!30,
        nodes = {circle, minimum size=5mm, anchor=center, draw=black},
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
        row sep=3mm,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[trafficlight] (A) { \\  \\ \\};
\node[right= 2mm of A-1-1] {Score 1};
\node[right= 2mm of A-2-1] {Score 2};
\node[right= 2mm of A-3-1] {Score 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,xcolor}
\setstackgap{L}{16pt}
\savestack\trafficlight{%
  \stackinset{c}{.1pt}{c}{-1pt}{%
    \Longstack{\textcolor{red}{\Huge$\bullet$} \textcolor{yellow}{\Huge$\bullet$} 
    \textcolor{green}{\Huge$\bullet$}}%
  }{\textcolor{blue!30!gray}{\rule[-1ex]{3.5ex}{4\baselineskip}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\Longstack[l]{Score 21--30\\ Score 11--20\\ Score 1--10} \trafficlight
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or if no corresponding side-text is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,xcolor}
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\savestack\trafficlight{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \Shortstack{\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{yellow}{$\bullet$} 
    \textcolor{green}{$\bullet$}}%
  }{\textcolor{blue!30!gray}{\rule{1.55ex}{4.2ex}}}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a \trafficlight.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is a  short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{fillstyle = solid}\everypsbox{\bfseries\textbullet\hspace{0.6em}Score }
\begin{psmatrix}[emnode = p, rowsep = 0.4cm]%
    [name = rlight] \\ [name = olight] \\ [name = glight]
    \ncbox[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = SteelBlue3, linearc = 0.3, nodesepA = 0.7cm, nodesepB = 0.45cm, boxsize = 0.5]{rlight}{glight}
    \foreach \l/\colour in {rlight/red, olight/Orange1, glight/SpringGreen2} {\pscircle[fillcolor = \colour](\l){0.3cm}}
    \nput{180}{rlight}{\makebox[8cm][l]{21--30: high anaphylactic risk (Step 3)}}
    \nput{180}{olight}{\makebox[8cm][l]{11--20: medium anaphylactic risk (Step 2)}}
    \nput{180}{glight}{\makebox[8cm][l]{1--10: low anaphylactic risk (Step 1B/1A)}}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For some reason nobody has animated the traffic light yet. You can use the `animate` package together with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    \multiframe{3}{n=1+1}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tcolor{ifthenelse(\n==3,100,20)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mcolor{ifthenelse(\n==2,100,20)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bcolor{ifthenelse(\n==1,100,20)}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[circle,minimum size=5mm, anchor=center, draw=black, fill=red!\tcolor](top){};
            \node[below = 5mm of top,circle,minimum size=5mm, anchor=center, draw=black, fill=yellow!\mcolor](middle){};
            \node[below = 5mm of middle,circle,minimum size=5mm, anchor=center, draw=black, fill=green!\bcolor](bottom){};
            \node[right= 2mm of top] {High risk};
            \node[right= 2mm of middle] {Medium risk};
            \node[right= 2mm of bottom] {Low risk};
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \node[draw,rounded corners,draw = blue!70,fill = blue!30,,fit=(top) (middle) (bottom)] {};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The animation aside, this solution is more elegant, and suited to customization. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid](5,5)
    \psframe[fillcolor=NavyBlue,framearc=.2](2,5)
    \pscircle[fillcolor=green](1,1){.5}\rput(3.5,1){Score 1--10}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=yellow](1,2.5){.5}\rput(3.5,2.5){Score 11--20}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=red](1,4){.5}\rput(3.5,4){Score 21--30}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animation

Just in case you need an animation but without the Adobe Reader window.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid](5,5)
    \psframe[fillcolor=NavyBlue,framearc=.2](2,5)
    \ifnum\i=3\relax
        \pscircle[fillcolor=green](1,1){.5}
    \else
        \pscircle[fillcolor=green!5](1,1){.5}
    \fi
    \ifnum\i=1\relax
        \pscircle[fillcolor=yellow](1,2.5){.5}
    \else
        \pscircle[fillcolor=yellow!5](1,2.5){.5}
    \fi
    \ifnum\i=2\relax
        \pscircle[fillcolor=red](1,4){.5}
    \else
        \pscircle[fillcolor=red!5](1,4){.5}
    \fi
    \rput[l](3,1){Score 1--10}
    \rput[l](3,2.5){Score 11--20}
    \rput[l](3,4){Score 21--30}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]